# JQuery Mobile Form Submission From and To Dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog

I am planning on using a dialog to let a user log into my jquery mobile application.

Basic functionality is that user will enter username and password.

- If incorrect the dialog will remain open.
- If correct then I'm going to close dialog and get user to another
  page.

My problem is that. One thing I noticed was that in order to keep my dialog, as a dialog, I had to mark the data-role of the containing "page" as a dialog. But another issue is that each time I post back, the location hash appends the form submission. So if I enter my password information twice incorrectly and decide to close dialog, I will have click cancel three times.

My url will start looking like this:

```
/Mobile/jobs#&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog&ui-state=dialog
```

My question is how can I control that behavior, so that posts don't result in additional information being added to the location hash?